# answers that have nothing to do with the question

Tags: support

[In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709463/c-sharp-macro-definitions-in-preprocessor) about macros in C#, there are two answers (from Dana and Iain Ballard) that have to do with retrying a function call when it throws an exception. These answers have nothing to do with the question. The public edit history doesn't show that the content of the question was changed.

Any idea what happened here? A bad merge, maybe?

Comment: So tempted to give an answer that has nothing to do with the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is ... super weird.

I don't see any evidence of a question merge in this case. The best I can figure out is that Dana posted a new question as an answer (which was eventually deleted), then responded to it in the same thread and so did Iain Ballard. Why? No idea.

I removed both of those answers.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like a bad merge to me. There is a deleted answer which appears to be the question that matches these two answers at the bottom of that page.

[image: del img]

Perhaps these three were merged over for some reason as answers, even the question - which was then subsequently deleted.

Either that, or someone posted a question as an answer and then they and another user posted an answer to their question as an answer which is a little unlikely.

Comment: Not that unlikely: just mistaking SO for a forum with threads.

Comment: There was no merge in this case.